# meaning of "Operation Stork"

Tags: meaning, phrase-meaning

What are the meanings of "Operation Stork"? I know the common meanings of the word "Operation" and "Stork", but putting the meanings together doesn't make sense to me.

PS：I saw this phase as the name for a photo album about a newborn baby.

Comment: _Stork_ is the name by which the operation is called, as in any other operation that has a name, as Operation Overlord or Operation Torch. I don't quite understand the question, you want to know that, or what Operation Stork is about?

Comment: "operation" can mean 1. surgery 2. management 3. computation. Which meaning is it in "operation stork"?

Comment: If I saw someone mention "Operation Stork" out of the blue, and the context was not either military or some sort of business where such terms might be used, I would assume they were talking about delivering a baby ("[the arrival of the stork](http://cliparts.co/cliparts/kT8/o7B/kT8o7BjRc.jpg)").

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it seems to be about the name of a specific (military?) campaign, not the use of English

Comment: Dony, as can be seen, a awful lot depends on the context, which you did not provide us.

Comment: There have been several operations Stork, and all of them involve people helping children or parents in need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's only been seen on a baby-photo-album, I think it's likely to be a little jokesy title.

It's thought to be traditional to tell a newborn's siblings that the baby was brought by a stork. Imagine a stork flying in with its precious cargo, in imitation of a plane on a mission - or *operation*.

(Whether the stork is going to drop a bombshell or humanitarian aid, only time will tell.)

Comment: Upvote. Should be accepted.

Answer (score 3):

In the context you mention, *Operation* means, according to the [OED](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/operation):

> An organized activity involving a number of people.

So, *Operation Stork* is an organized activity involving a number of people, that happens to be called "Stork" to differentiate itself.

**EDIT-** Additional info:
There was in fact an Operation Stork, which involved [bringing orphans from Haiti to Canada](http://www.theglobeandmail.com/news/politics/ottawa-notebook/operation-stork-delivers-more-haitian-orphans/article4351590/). The conection of "bringing children" with stork is clear.

Comment: Most likely this is a euphemism for "giving birth".

Comment: @A.Ellett There was in fact an _Operation Stork_, and it involved [bringing Haitian orphans to Canada](http://www.theglobeandmail.com/news/politics/ottawa-notebook/operation-stork-delivers-more-haitian-orphans/article4351590/), but as the question is not very clear, I believe the person who asked just wants to know what "operation + something" means.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense.  Thanks for explaining.  :-)